# Is the default value of malloc with the size of a single char P?

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, conversion-specifier

```
char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char));
printf("\nValue of ptr: %d\n",ptr);
printf("\nValue of address of ptr: %x\n",&ptr);
printf("\nValue of pointed by ptr: %c\n",*ptr);
printf("\nValue of address pointed by ptr: %x\n",&(*ptr));
*ptr='u';
 printf("\nValue of pointed by ptr: %c\n",*ptr);
printf("\nValue of address pointed by ptr: %x\n",&(*ptr));
```

In the above piece of code, the following output is received:

```
Value of ptr: 1046113600
Value of address of ptr: a2fffa78
Value of pointed by ptr: P
Value of address pointed by ptr: 3e5a6d40
Value of pointed by ptr: u
Value of address pointed by ptr: 3e5a6d40
```

Does this imply that the default value of the malloc with a single char size is P?

Tried to allocate memory of single char size using malloc and initialized a pointer pointing to the allocated memory. Tried to print the value of the allocated memory.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your format specifiers are wrong. For printing a pointer you must use `%p`, not `%d or `%x.

Comment: the value is indeterminate.

Comment: You should also be aware that `&(*ptr)` is identical to `ptr` as `&*` or `*&` cancel each other out. You can see that `1046113600` is the same as `0x3E5A6D40`. And both are likely not the value returned by `malloc` because nowadays addresses are likely to be 64bit wide while integers are mostly 32 bits.

Comment: Hey @Gerhardh, thanks for explaining. I have a question here. What does ptr represent here exactly? Is it the address of the allocated memory or is it the value of the ptr variable(pointing to the allocated memory) or both are the same?

Comment: Neuronb ptr is a variable of type char *. Its value is the address of the memory allocated by malloc() (assuming success).

Comment: The "value of the pointer variable" is the same as "the address of the allocated memory" in this case as you assign that address to that variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc` allocates memory without initializing it.  So the allocated memory can contain any set of bit values. Neither default value is used.

Opposite to malloc you can use another allocating function `calloc` that zero initializes the allocated memory as for example

```
char *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
```

Pay attention to that such calls of printf to output values of pointers like

```
printf("\nValue of ptr: %d\n",ptr);
printf("\nValue of address of ptr: %x\n",&ptr);
```

are invalid and have undefined behavior. In particularly for example the conversion specifier `d` is designed to output integers of the type `int` and `sizeof( int )` can be equal to `4` while `sizeof( char * )` can be equal to `8`.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
> undefined.275) If any argument is not the correct type for the
> corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

You should use either the conversion specifier `p` with pointers as for example

```
printf("\nValue of ptr: %p\n", ( void * )ptr);
```

or conversion specifiers defined in header `<inttypes.h>`

```
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

printf("\nValue of ptr: %" PRIdPTR "\n", ( intptr_t )( void * )ptr);
```

Comment: Hi @Vlad from Moscow, thank you so much for your detailed answer. Can you please help me clarify some questions or confusions? So the ptr here is pointing to an uninitialized memory allocation(char *ptr=malloc). Now my question is whether outputing ptr(using %p) will return the address of the allocated memory or will it return the value of the variable ptr(which is pointing to the allocated memory) or are both of them same?

Comment: @NeuronB - The value of the the variable `ptr` happens to be a number which corresponds to an address in memory.  They are the same.  The format specifier `%p` expects a pointer, and will output that value.  Outputting the contents of memory is done as you have shown in your question: `printf("\nValue contained in memory pointed to by ptr: %c\n",*ptr);` (with a minor edit to wording.)

Comment: Thanks @ryyker for explaining this. Much appreciate it. So the line that you just commented does seem to output a character after malloc (P in this case). Is it a garbage value?

Comment: @NeuronB You are right. It is a garbage value.

Answer (score 8):

There is no "default value", as `malloc` does not initialize the memory. Its value is indeterminate. To initialize memory you can either use `calloc` instead which allocates and then sets all bytes to zero, or you can initialize the memory yourself.

Comment: Thanks @paddy. By "initialize the memory yourself", did you mean something like *ptr='u'?

Comment: Yes, something like that.